# Handling namespace models (classes) in namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, namespaces

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to handle models (classes) namespaces within namespaces. That is, if I have a namespace named *NS1* and a "sub-namespace" of that namespace named *NS2*, I would like to handle models (classes) in *NS2*.

If I run a *scaffold*

```
rails generate scaffold ns1/ns2/Article id:integer title:string
```

it will generate following model files:

```
models/ns1/ns2/article.rb file
models/ns1/articles.rb
```

The `models/ns1/articles.rb` contains:

```
module Ns1::Articles
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'ns1_articles_'
  end
end
```

What is the `models/ns1/articles.rb` file? How and why can I use that? Have you advices about using that?

*And, in general, what is "the best" way to handle "composed" classes in namespaces using Ruby on Rails?*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The

> models/ns1/articles.rb

is basically setting the table name prefix for all the model classes under that namespace. Thats its use. It's more DRY'ish to do in there (in a single file), rather than setting the prefix in every model class under that namespace.

I am not a big fan of using namespaces in my models. However you could refer to the following articles to gain a better understanding about using namespaces in modules.

- [Namespaced models and controllers](http://venkatev.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/namespaced-models-and-controllers/)

Some alternatives to using namespaces in models

- [A simple alternative to namespaced models](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/5/6/a-simple-alternative-to-namespaced-models)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if you want to have a model named ns1? What do you do then?

Comment: why are you not a fan of namespaced models?