# How to namespace models\classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, namespaces

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.1 and I would like to "(re)name"\"use" *namespaced* model files and related classes "a là Ruby on Rails Way" keeping current database table names. That is, I have the following file system:

```
- app/models/article.rb
- app/models/articles.rb
- app/models/articles/comment.rb
- app/models/articles/category.rb
- app/models/articles/...
```

Related database table names are respectively:

```
# Note: Since the 'app/models/articles.rb' file is related to a module (read
# below for more information) it has not a related database table
- articles
- articles_comments
- articles_categories
- ...
```

In the `app/models/articles.rb` file I have:

```
module Articles
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'articles_'
  end
end
```

For istance, in the `app/models/articles/comment.rb` I have

```
class Articles::Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

**Is that the right way to "name"\"use" namespaced classes?**

---

Maybe the "right" way to make that is to namespace to *singular* names (eg: to use `class Article::Comment ... end` instead of `class Articles::Comment ... end`) and, in order to organize files, to use the `/article/` directory instead of `/articles/`. In this case the file system should be:

```
# Note: the 'app/models/articles.rb', maybe, should not be present
- app/models/article.rb
- app/models/article/comment.rb
- app/models/article/category.rb
- app/models/article/...
```

If so, **how it should work for the `app/models/articles.rb` file** (no more present in the last example) **in order to keep database table name prefix to `articles`?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling namespace models (classes) in namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852626/handling-namespace-models-classes-in-namespace) created by this same user a few months ago.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - If you read the old question, (for me) it is substantially different than the current.

Comment: I don't understand your article.rb as module, what's the point?

Comment: @apneadiving - I would like to easy-organize my model files (maybe, using namespaces simplify that "job").

Answer (score 0):

The rails way is to not do this.

You'll only use namespaced models and controllers for big-huge logical separations. For example, if you have Admin models that are only applicable during administration, you might have:

```
app/admin/report.rb
app/admin/dashboard.rb
```

And you'd reference them as Admin::Report

But there is no "Admin" object -- in your example, you have an "Article" object... I would not group your files in this manner... keep them all in the app's global namespace.

Comment: And if I have a "big-huge" logical separations, what I can make?