# Models with reserved keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a model called 'File', but it is a reserved model name is rails. I can't think of anything else sane to call the model, so I was wondering if there  is a standard way of dealing with this issue, for example adding a prefix or suffix (_File, FileItem, etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is addressed with [modules](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html):

> Modules are a way of grouping together methods, classes, and
>   constants. Modules give you two major benefits:
>
> 1. Modules provide a namespace and prevent name clashes.
> 2. Modules implement the mixin facility.
>
> [...]
>
> **Modules define a namespace**, a sandbox in which your methods and
>   constants can play without having to worry about being stepped on by
>   other methods and constants.

In your case:

```
module MyRailsApp
  class File
  ...
  end
end
```

whereby your `File` class is used as `MyRailsApp::File`. This is the typical solution in Ruby, in Ruby on Rails this might be handled differently, please see the following references for an in depth discussion:

- [Handling namespace models (classes) in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852626/handling-namespace-models-classes-in-namespace)
- [ActiveRecord: Can haz namespaces?](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html)
- [Namespaced models and controllers](http://venkatev.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/namespaced-models-and-controllers/)
- [Namespaced models](http://m.onkey.org/namespaced-models)
- [A simple alternative to namespaced models](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/5/6/a-simple-alternative-to-namespaced-models)

Comment: How do you put a model in a module in rails?

Comment: @CameronMartin Not different than you put a class in a module.

Comment: You can create models in modules by doing `rails generate model modulename/modelname` right? Is it better to put all your models in a module, or choose a non-conflicting name?

Comment: @CameronMartin That is a good question, after all this topic has its own discussion ongoing. I've added additional references which discuss this problem, since it seems there is no clear answer.