# Generate Rails Model named "Signal"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to generate a rails model like so:

`rails generate model signal`

Which produced this error:

`The name 'Signal' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.`

I quickly discovered that "Signal" was a reserved name for models:

[Reserved names with ActiveRecord models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750009/reserved-names-with-activerecord-models)

Is there any way around this so I can have a model named "Signal", like wrapping the model in a custom `Module`?

Comment: Signal is part of the Ruby Standard Library: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Signal.html. Just name your class something like MySignal.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821146/models-with-reserved-keywords