# rails how to properly move models to a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, models

I'm running rails v 3.2 .
After some time developing application I need to move some models into namespace ex: `/app/models/address.rb` to `/app/models/local/address.rb`
I tried simply moving models to destination folder and adding `Local::` to the class name. then i accordingly update specs, and i still get an error on running spec.he . `uninitialized constant Address (NameError)`.
The question is - How can i move models to a namespace? what are my actions - editing migrations or something else... Please help because i got mixed up by different articles & etc.

**Update**
I found out what's the problem:
Devise and namespaces. solving it

Comment: Have a look http://venkatev.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/namespaced-models-and-controllers/,

Comment: They're not worth it! I'm swearing them off after the project I'm on now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852626/handling-namespace-models-classes-in-namespace

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can try this:

create a new rails project, then run

```
rails g model Local::Address city:string country:string
```

Now you can see how rails handle namespace for model. You can just follow the way to modify yours.